# Searching lists that are part of other lists in python

Tags: python, list, indexing

Here is my list :

```
list =  [[4, '+', 6, '=', 10], [['?', 4], ['+', 0], ['?', 2], ['=', 0], ['?', 'a']]]
```

I need to find the index of the second list where the first element is '?' no matter what the second element is,

In this example the answer I want is 1 because the sublist `['?',4]` is the correct occurrence.

I've tried :

```
[x for x, y in enumerate[list] if y[0] == '?']
[y[0] for y in list].index('?')
list[1,[0]].index('?')
```

I know I could write a routine but you'd think there was a one statement solution.

Comment: So you want your one line statement to output the index( 1 in this case)?

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit unclear. I think that what you mean (according to the code you posted) is the index in the second list, of the sublist whose first value is ?. If that's the case, you can use:

```
(i for i,x in enumerate(lst[1]) if x[0] == '?').next()
```

However, not that if the second list is

```
[['?', 4], ['+', 0], ['?', 2], ['=', 0], ['?', 'a']]
```

Then the index of `['?', 4]` is 0, as pythons indexes are usually 0-based. If you want it to be 1, just add one.

Answer (score -1):

**Solution:**

```
>>> lst = [[4, '+', 6, '=', 10], [['?', 4], ['+', 0], ['?', 2], ['=', 0], ['?', 'a']]]
>>> [x for x, y in enumerate(lst) if y[0] == '?']
[0, 2, 4] #the indexes of the locations of the '?')
```

as lst has 3 nested lists, y[0] returns `4` and `['?', 4]`. You can't do y[0][0] as the first return is an integer (no slicing options), but you can just loop through the second nested list (`[['?', 4], ['+', 0], ['?', 2], ['=', 0], ['?', 'a']]`) instead. Only works, of course, if you do not need to loop through the first one!